# SQL Select Count from below a certain age

Tags: sql, database, select

I'm trying to get a count of people in a table below a certain age.  Something like this

```
select count(*) as total from 'TABLE' where 'BIRTHDAY'> 19 years old ;
```

The field type is DATE for BIRTHDAY

I'm new to sql and I am just not sure how to write this properly.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Love the Query being in simple English!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQL Server and MySQL, you could look to use the `DATEDIFF` function

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table WHERE DATEDIFF(year,BIRTHDAY,today) > 19
```

(replacing the today bit with the relevant command for the RDBMS you are using to get today's date (ie: GETDATE() for SQL Server)

Comment: Just FYI, don't know about SQL Server, but in MySQL for example an index couldn't be used when written like this, as the column is in a function. IIRC an index can be created on a function call, though. Still it's easier to just rearrange, so that the column is on one side and the calculation on the other.

Comment: But I don't know of any flavor of SQL where you can index on a function that includes a non-deterministic value like "today". But the problem is easily solved, use where birthday<today - interval 19 years (or whatever the equivalent is on your db -- I don't think the date inverval stuff is standard). That way you calculate the "threshold birthday" once rather than calculate each persons age. But we're probably getting beyond what the original poster is prepared to handle -- he's admittedly a newbie.

Comment: I'm confused now - this code SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Employees WHERE DATEDIFF(year,DOB,GETDATE()) > 200 runs on SQL Server 2008 and returns the results I expect

Comment: Noone said the result wouldn't be right. Just that an index can not be used this way.

Comment: This worked! Thanks for all the advice. For firebird, I had to use cast('Now' as date) to replace the parameter today in the DATEDIFF function.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL you can do:

```
select count(*) as total from TABLE where BIRTHDAY < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 19 YEAR;
```

And note: You don't want to use `'` around tablename or column name, as this makes them a string and your statement fails.

Comment: +1 for pointing out not to use the ' around table/column name to the OP

Comment: I was just using ' for emphasis. I got this error              Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -104.
Token unknown - line 1, column 78.
19.

Comment: See? That's what you get for not specifying exactly which database system you're using ;)