# Performing COUNT() on a computed Column from a VIEW

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, view, count, calculated-columns

So all I want to do is have a view that shows how many kid between and including the age of 5 - 18 are in each family. I AM USING SQL SERVER.

The view I Have written to get the Family Members Ages is

```
CREATE VIEW VActiveMembers
AS
    SELECT 
        TM.intMemberID AS intMemberID,
        TM.strFirstName AS strFirstName,
        TM.strLastName AS strLastName,
        TM.strEmailAddress AS strEmailAddress,
        TM.dtmDateOfBirth AS dtmDateOfBirth,
        FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DAY, dtmDateOfBirth, GETDATE()) / 365.25) AS intMemberAge
    FROM 
        TMembers AS TM
    WHERE 
        TM.intStatusFlagID = 1
```

`intStatusFlag = 1` is just a flag that means the member is active.

Now I have tried for about 3ish hours to figure this out but I cannot figure it out. Here is the one where instead of trying to get the solution in one fowl swoop I tried to step wise it, but then I still didn't get the result I wanted.

As you can see I didn't use the view where I calculated the AGE from because the "Multi-part Identifier could not be bound" I have seen that error but I couldn't get it to go away in this case. Ideally I would like the count to be performed on the VIEW instead of recalculating the ages all over again

```
CREATE VIEW VActiveFamilyMembersK12Count
AS
    SELECT
        TF.intParishFamilyID,
        COUNT(DATEDIFF(DAY, dtmDateOfBirth, GETDATE()) / 365) AS intMemberAgeCount
    FROM 
        TFamilies AS TF
    INNER JOIN 
        TFamilyMembers AS TFM
    INNER JOIN 
        VActiveMembers AS vAM ON (TFM.intMemberID = vAM.intMemberID)
        ON (TFM.intParishFamilyID = TF.intParishFamilyID) 
    WHERE 
        TF.intStatusFlagID = 1
    GROUP BY 
        TF.intParishFamilyID
```

I wanted to just get a count using the age calculation just to see If I could get a correct count of members in a family, then I could start building upon that to get a count of members of a certain age. The result I get back is 2 but there are guaranteed 3 members to each family.

The result I am looking For is this

```
Family_ID    |     K12Count
-----------------------------
1001         |        2
1002         |        0
1003         |        1
1004         |        0
```

Here is a list of resources I looked up trying to figure this out, maybe one of them is in fact the answer and I just don't see it, but I am at a loss at the moment.

[SQL Select Count from below a certain age](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21141849/sql-select-count-from-below-a-certain-age)

[How to get count of people based on age groups using SQL query in Oracle database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31667844/how-to-get-count-of-people-based-on-age-groups-using-sql-query-in-oracle-databas)

[Count number of user in a certain age's range base on date of birth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34822906/count-number-of-user-in-a-certain-ages-range-base-on-date-of-birth)

[Conditional Count on a field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288058/conditional-count-on-a-field)

http://timmurphy.org/2010/10/10/conditional-count-in-sql/

*** EDIT ***

```
CREATE VIEW VActiveFamilyMembersK12Count
AS
SELECT 
TF.intParishFamilyID, 
SUM(CASE WHEN intMemberAge >= 5 AND intMemberAge <= 18 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS intK12Count
FROM 
TFamilies AS TF
    INNER JOIN TFamilyMembers AS TFM
        INNER JOIN VActiveMembers AS vAM
        ON (TFM.intMemberID = vAM.intMemberID)
    ON (TFM.intParishFamilyID = TF.intParishFamilyID) 

WHERE 
TF. intStatusFlagID = 1

GROUP BY 
TF.intParishFamilyID

GO
```

THIS IS THE SOLUTION ABOVE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional count is the way to go.
Something like:

```
SELECT intParishFamilyID, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN intMemberAge >=5 and intMemberAge <=18 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM 
    TFamilies AS TF
        INNER JOIN TFamilyMembers AS TFM
            INNER JOIN VActiveMembers AS vAM
            ON (TFM.intMemberID = vAM.intMemberID)
        ON (TFM.intParishFamilyID = TF.intParishFamilyID) 

WHERE 
    TF. intStatusFlagID = 1

GROUP BY 
    TF.intParishFamilyID
```